# R data in created column got truncated

Tags: r

I want to convert datetime to date in mm/dd/yyyy format in R. The data in the new column I created got truncated. You can see the example using below code. In the row #6, the desired output is 11/16/2016, however it shows 11/16/201.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c("2/23/2017 4:45", "2/15/2017 21:46", "2/10/2017 4:20", 
    "2/9/2017 7:19", "2/7/2017 3:23", "11/16/2016 0:58")

test <- as.data.frame(a)

test %>% mutate(new = substr(a, 1, regexpr(" ",a)[1]-1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have date values, then you are better off working with them as date values rather than using regular expressions and substrings. Here's a helper function to parse the data into a dplyr friendly format

```
parsect <- function(x, f="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") {
    as.POSIXct(strptime(x, f))
}
```

Then you can do

```
test %>% mutate(new = strftime(parsect(a), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The `parsect()` will turn the value into a proper date/time value, then you can use the base `strftime()` function to format that date/time.

Although it looks like your method would have worked without the `[1]` part because `regexpr()` is vectorized.

```
test %>% mutate(new = substr(a, 1, regexpr(" ",a)-1))
```

The `[1]` forced all rows to use the position where the space was found in the first value.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation! It works now.